# How to disable Chrome spell check on INPUT with HTML or jQuery code?

Tags: html, firefox, input, google-chrome, spell-checking

I have an input in an HTML page

```
<input id="SearchBox" type="text" value="" width="300px" 
       title="Search the card pool" autocomplete="off" maxlength="170">
```

I would like to switch this off with something like autospellcheck="off". Is there a way to achieve that?

Is there also a way to switch this off for Firefox?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the `spellcheck` attribute:

```
<textarea spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

See [Spellcheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSDN) or [Controlling spell checking in HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms) (MDN).

Answer (score 5):

add the attribute using JQuery $('.textarea_className').attr('spellcheck',false);

I was able to do this with JQUery so that I can return 0 errors for my XHTML validation

Comment: Just cause you add a attribute via JS does not make it valid XHTML, change your doctype to html5